# Jquery - Using $(this).attr("id") makes a click listener stop working

Tags: jquery

I have a poll creator that can have several questions. In order to make it simple, my script has a question counter to help group the choices of each question. But this means that when I create a new question, I can no longer add choices to previous questions, or they will be grouped incorrectly.

So I added an id for each add_choice button, one in each question

```
function addChoice(){
    $(this).before('<p><input id="choice" name="option' + question_counter + '[]" type="text"  placeholder="Enter Choice"/>' +
                        '<a title="Delete Choice" id="' + question_counter + '"class="delete_choice" href="#question_container">AAA</a>' +
                        '</p>'); 
    $(".delete_choice").click(deleteChoice);
}

function addQuestion(){
    question_counter++;
    $(".add_choice").remove();
    $(this).before('<fieldset class="new_question"><legend id="legend_' + question_counter + '">Question ' + question_counter + '</legend>' + 
                   '<p class="questionbar">' + 
                   '<label for="question_title">Question Title</label><br>' + 
                   '<input class="questionbar" type="text" placeholder="Question Title" name="question_title_' + question_counter +'" required><br>' +
                   '</p>' + 
                   '<div class="choice_container">' + 
                   '<p id="' + question_counter + '"class="add_choice"><a title="Add New Choice" href="#question_container"><span><img src="images/add_choice_icon.png" style="width:30px; height:30px"></span></a></p>' + 
                   '</div>' + 
                    '<p class="delete_question"><a title="Delete Question" href="#"><span><img src="images/delete_icon.png" style="width:30px; height:30px"></span></a></p>' + 
                   '</fieldset>');

    $(".questionbar").keyup(addQuestionTitle);
    $(".delete_choice").click(deleteChoice);
    $(".delete_question").click(deleteQuestion);
    $(".add_choice").click(addChoice);
}
```

So in my addChoice function, I used

```
var cid = $(this).attr("id");
```

In order to group the choices to the question, since the add_choice button will have the same id as the question I want to add the choice to.
But the moment I use this, the addQuestion function stops working. Not even an alert() will do anything.
Am I using this incorrectly, or is this a sign of other problems?

Comment: You're question is very hard to understand in its current form Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You appear to be adding duplicate `id="choice"` entries, which is invalid HTML and jQuery can only find the first match by id. Use classes instead.

Comment: Thanks, TrueBlueAussie, that seems to have solved it. But if I was trying to get the id of the button, why did the id of the choice get in the way, if it didn't even exist at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is conceptionally wrong.

1. You should use event delegation.
2. You don't need global element counter variables. Get rid of them.
3. You have repeating elements but don't use unique HTML IDs. Make them unique or get rid of them.
4. You are in need of a templating solution.

Here is an approach that fixes all four points. I've used [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) as the template engine.

First you must define HTML templates:

```
<script id="question-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <fieldset class="new_question" data-num="{{num}}">
        <legend>Question {{num}}</legend>
        <p class="questionbar">
            <label for="question_title_{{num}}">Question Title</label><br>
            <input class="questionbar" type="text" placeholder="Question Title" id="question_title_{{num}}" name="question_title_{{num}}" required /></br>
        </p>
        <div class="choice_container">
            <p id="question_{{num}}" class="add_choice">
                <a title="Add New Choice" href="#question_container">
                    <span><img src="images/add_choice_icon.png" alt="Add Choice" /></span>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <p class="delete_question">
            <a title="Delete Question" href="#" class=".delete_question">
                <span><img src="images/delete_icon.png" alt="Delete" /></span>
            </a>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</script>

<script id="choice-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p class="choice">
        <input id="choice" name="option_{{num}}[]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Choice"/>
        <a title="Delete Choice" class="delete_choice" href="#question_container">Delete Choice</a>
    </p>
</script>
```

And then you can use them.

```
// compile templates
var choiceTemplate = Handlebars.compile( $("#choice-template").text() );
var questionTemplate = Handlebars.compile( $("#question-template").text() );

// define event handlers
// ...

// attach event handlers via event delegation dele
$(document)
.on("click", "#addQuestion", addQuestion)
.on("click", ".delete_question a", deleteQuestion)
.on("click", ".questionbar", addQuestionTitle)
.on("click", ".add_choice a", addChoice)
.on("click", ".delete_choice", deleteChoice);

// done
```

See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/jkyvwbb2/1/